# iOS - How to get ip Call status?

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call, core-telephony

How do we find out the status of IP calls (i.e skype or any other internet calls). I have used core telephony framework to find the phone call status, however I haven't find any good solution to find IP call status. Any idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You could listen for the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` to know about the in call banner however thats not recommended for various reasons:

1. The status bar can change size for more than just IP calls (normal calls, navigation, personal hotspot etc).
2. It doesn't change size on iPad

I can only guess that you wanted to detect this to adjust your UI, if that is the case you should probably be using Auto Layout to avoid this anyway... If you wanted to actually detect when the user is making calls then like I said, you aren't able to do that unfortunately.